# JavaScript random generate 0 or 1 integer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate random 0 or 1 as I am writing a script to populdate my database. If it is 1, I will save it as male and 0 the other way around.

Inside my JavaScript:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
```

I used this to generate either 1 or 0. However, with the code above, it always return me with 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random()  + 0.5);

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You can use `Math.round(Math.random())`. If `Math.random()` generates a number less than 0.5 the result will be 0 otherwise it should be 1.

Comment: let oneOrZero = (Math.random()>0.5)? 1 : 0;

Comment: @Combine Should that be `let oneOrZero = (Math.random()>=0.5)? 1 : 0;`?

Comment: to have fifty-fifty use Chad Johnson's

Answer (score 2):

There is a `+1` with Math.random, so it will always going to add 1 to the randomly generated number.
You can just randomly generate a number, since Math.random will generate any floating number between 0 & 1, then use if.. else to assign 0 or 1

```js
var y = Math.random();
if (y < 0.5)
  y = 0
else
  y= 1
console.log(y)
```

Comment: `console.log(Math.random()<0.5?0:1)`